# Failed to create the VirtualBox object

Tags: bash, vagrant, virtual-machine

I was trying to login into the already existing vm using vagrant in bash. But it says failed to start or it's not running.

This is a already existing vm in the local.

I tried 
`$vagrant global-status` -> to get the vm id.

then,
`$vagrant up <id>` ->to start the vm.

Got the following error,

> There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
>   for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.
>
> Command: ["showvminfo", "cd2ec772-3e94-476f-a0d9-59c3d2768fb5"]
>   Stderr: VBoxManage.exe: error: Failed to create the VirtualBox object!
>
> VBoxManage.exe: error: Code REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG (0x80040154) - Class not registered (extended info not available)
>   VBoxManage.exe: error: Most likely, the VirtualBox COM server is not running or failed to start.